# Do neural networks with binary output learn representations that are linearly separable?

Tags: multiple-regression, deep-learning

Support Vector machines employ the kernel trick in order to find a space where the data is mostly linearly separable and then determine what the appropriate hyperplane. However, back in the original space, the hyperplane would look non-linear.

Neural networks also learn a non-linear decision boundary through the use of the non-linear activation functions. However, the output representation of the final layer is therefore the representation that will be used to finally classify the data.

In the case of a binary classification task, it the case that the best representation that can be learned is likely to one that allows data to be linearly separable?

Answer (score 0):

If you use non-linear activation functions (e.g. ReLu, tanh, logit) and have at least one hidden layer, then the neural-network can indeed learn non-linear separation boundaries.

Solving the XOR function is a famous historical example of using a NN with a hidden layer to classify data that are not linearly separable. [This article](http://lab.fs.uni-lj.si/lasin/wp/IMIT_files/neural/nn04_mlp_xor/) shows it nicely and I stole the image from the bottom of the article illustrating the decision boundary learned for data that are not linearly separable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes it is a non linear decision boundary but my question is more about whether the neural network is “lifting the space” in the way the kernel trick does to separate the data. I believe that an appropriate kernel can also solve XOR.